# Print with Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, printing

I am trying to choose the printer in the default chrome dialog via a Chrome Extension, but have not be to get [PrinterProvider](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/printerProvider) events to trigger at all in my extension.  Is PrinterProvider the correct way to go about this? If so, any examples would be helpful.  Is it possible to select which printer name shows up in the printer dropdown?

For example, I have the following in my background.js and the event is never triggered:

```
chrome.printerProvider.onPrintRequested.addListener(async (chromePrintJob, printRequestCallback) => {
  console.log("Print requested");
  await chromePrintJob.document.text();
  console.log("resolve");
  printRequestCallback("OK");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to choose the printer in the default chrome dialog via a Chrome Extension

This isn't possible. Chrome does not give extensions that kind of control over its UI. Moreover, default printer selection is typically an OS-level setting.

> Is PrinterProvider the correct way to go about this?

No, that interface allows an extension to act as a printer, not to modify existing printers. In other words, you can use PrinterProvider in your extension to add new printers the user can select in the print dialog window and handle print jobs sent to your custom printer.

Comment: is there documentation or an example of how I would make a custom printer?  e.g. I can get a printer name to show up in the print dialog box, but how would I configure a custom printer?  Is that all done in Chrome Extension JavaScript?

Comment: Here's [a sample extension](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/_archive/mv2/api/printing) that shows basic usage of the API to create a printer. There's also a sample for [Chrome App printer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/_archive/apps/samples/printing/). Chrome Apps are deprecated, but have a lot in common with Chrome Extensions.

Comment: would this only work on a Chromebook though? https://3-72-0-dot-chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/extensions/printing

Comment: I'm afraid your right, the Printing API is restricted to Chrome OS ([source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/common/extensions/api/_permission_features.json;l=707;drc=3e6adf14ae670bedaf73f3d6fbf134b28ff345fa)). The current wording of the API docs doesn't make that obvious.